# Why doesn't App crash when I use collect a flow from the UI directly from launch in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have read the [article](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow#stateflow). I know the following content just like Image B.

*Warning: Never collect a flow from the UI directly from launch or the launchIn extension function if the UI needs to be updated. These functions process events even when the view is not visible. This behavior can lead to app crashes. To avoid that, use the repeatOnLifecycle API as shown above.*

But the Code A can work well without wrapped with `repeatOnLifecycle`, why?

**Code A**

```
@Composable
fun Greeting(handleMeter: HandleMeter,lifecycleScope: LifecycleCoroutineScope) {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()  
    ) {    
          
        var my by  remember { mutableStateOf(5)}

        Text(text = "OK ${my}")

        var dataInfo = remember { handleMeter.uiState }
        lifecycleScope.launch {
            dataInfo.collect { my=dataInfo.value }
        }
}


class HandleMeter: ViewModel() { 
    val uiState = MutableStateFlow<Int>(0)
    ...
}
```

**Image B**

[image]

Comment: The warning says it CAN crash and not that it WILL crash. If it crashed 100% of the time, no warning would be necessary because the error would be obvious. It warns you against sneaky error that's difficult to catch in testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code A will not work in real life. If you need to run some non-UI code in a composable function, use callbacks (like onClick) or LaunchedEffect (or other side effects).

```
LaunchedEffect {
    dataInfo.collect {my=dataInfo.value}
}
```

Side effects are bound to composables, there is no need to specify the owner of their lifecycle directly.

Also, you can easily convert any flow to state:

```
val my = handleMeter.uiState.collectAsState()
```